# why are they selecting our products or why do they select our products. Which one?

Tags: tenses

This one from Steve Jobs video, 00:42. He use "why are they selecting our products", could I use " why do they select our products"? what are the differences?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BNGMMc3Bgc

Comment: No, you could not. Your variant is not grammatically correct. You can say "Why are they selecting our products?" (I'd chose "choosing" instead of selecting, though) or "Why did they select our products?" if different tense fits overall structure.

Comment: This is a question about basic English grammar; as such, it is not a good fit for ELU. Have you seen our sister site, [ell.se], which is geared specifically towards learners of English? That would be a much better place to ask questions like this. Note that even there, you are expected to do a bit of research before asking and clearly state in the question what your research has been (dictionaries, grammar books, etc.) and why it didn’t help you.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I just updated. I should use "why do they select", not "why do they selecting".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Auxiliary *do* **must** be followed by the base form ("infinitive") of the main verb, not any other form.

Auxiliary *be* **must** be followed either by the *-ing* form ("present participle") for a progressive form, or by the "past participle" (*-ed* form, but takes many other shapes).

I suspect that you actually intended to ask about *why are they selecting* versus *why do they select*. Both are grammatical, and both are natural.

*Why do they select* is timeless: it is not talking about now specifically, but asking a general question. *Why are they selecting* is now: this week or this month or this year, as opposed to the previous or next period. (You can't tell from the words which timescale he is talking about)

Comment: Thank you. I made mistake, my question is why are they selecting versus why do they select. Your explanation is quite clear.